# Indecomposable integral representations of a group of order 2

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

This question is a duplicate of
[that 2010 MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27129/involutions-in-gl-nz/27145#27145).

I am interested in classifying isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional integral representations of the cyclic group $C_2$ of order $2$.
Clearly, any integral  representation of $C_2$ is a direct sum of *indecomposable* integral representations.

The following result is well-known:

> **Theorem.**
> The group $C_2$ has exactly 3 isomorphism classes of indecomposable integral representations:
>
> (1) trivial;
>
> (2) the  sign representation;
>
> (3) the 2-dimensional representation with matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right).$

This result was stated in [the MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27145/4149) of Victor Protsak.
In [his comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27129/involutions-in-gl-nz/27145#comment57961_27145)
Victor Protsak gives a reference. He writes: "Curtis and Reiner, Chapter 11.
It's a special case of a theorem in Section 74 which classifies integral representations of cyclic groups of prime order.
Naturally, this case is much easier and can be done by hand."

> **Question.** How to prove the above theorem "by hand", without reference to the book by Curtis and Reiner?

**Motivation:** I am working now with algebraic $\mathbb R$-tori.
They are classified by integral representations of the Galois group
${\rm Gal}({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb R})$, which is a group of order $2$.
In order to understand the well-known classification of indecomposable $\mathbb R$-tori,
I need to understand the well-known classification
of indecomposable  integral representations of ${\rm Gal}({\mathbb C}/{\mathbb R})$.

Comment: Cross-posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/369239/4149).